# Select two distinct colums in bigquery based on third colums value

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have some campaign data from Google Analytics that i want to chrunch in Bigquery with SQL. There are two dimension columns, campaign and adcontent, and one metric, sessions.
It would be simple if not some traffic come in with a bad campaign parameter and i end up with a bad looking table. What i want to do now is to "group" the sessions together on one adcontent and on the campaign with the highest count of sessions.

I tried some different options to join with TOP but this is always with two different tables, and i can´t get it to work here.

TABLE

```
adcontent       campaign            sessions
adcontent_1     campaign_1          57
adcontent_1     wrong_campaign_1    1
adcontent_2     campaign_2          102
adcontent_2     wrong_campaign_1    3
```

RESULT TABLE:

```
adcontent   campaign    sessions
adcontent_1 campaign_1  58
adcontent_2 campaign_2  105
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to keep the campaign name that has the most sessions.  BigQuery doesn't have a "first" aggregation function, but you can use:

```
select adcontent,
       array_agg(campaign order by sessions desc limit 1)[safe_ordinal(1)] as leading_campaign
       sum(sessions) as sessions
from t
group by adcontent;
```

Here is an example of the code:

```
with t as (
      SELECT 'adcontent_1' as adcontent, 'campaign_1' as campaign, 57 as sessions union all
      SELECT 'adcontent_1', 'wrong_campaign_1', 1 union all
      SELECT 'adcontent_2', 'campaign_2', 102 union all
      SELECT 'adcontent_2', 'wrong_campaign_1', 3 UNION ALL
      SELECT 'adcontent_3', 'campaign_3', 42 union all
      SELECT 'adcontent_3', 'bad_campaign_3', 4
     )
select adcontent,
       array_agg(campaign order by sessions desc limit 1)[safe_ordinal(1)] as leading_campaign,
       sum(sessions) as sessions
from t
group by adcontent;
```

Answer (score 0):

use aggregation

```
adcontent,min(campaign),sum(sessions) from table 
group by adcontent
```

Comment: Wow. so simple! Thanks